# How can i draw a high chart with two labels in x coordinate using highchart

Tags: highcharts

How can I draw a high chart with two labels in x coordinate one is string another one is a date in highcharts
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xAxis.categories feature to achieve it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xj0dh8es/

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['test1', '04/07','05/07','06/07']
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Comment: Thank Sebastian. One more question how to integrate column chart and stack chart in a single chart. 

Forex: In category, test1 is a column chart and the remaining categories are stack chart. Please help me.

Comment: @Satyanarayana would you like to achieve something like in this demo? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j2y6mxz8/